# java query linking error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

i am working on generating webpages in php mysql.

the javascript file is not working.its throwing an error- The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

The three files are:

First file code is: indexmain1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Searching sites</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="go" name="go" size="80"/>&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="searchsite" id="submit" value="search site"/>
<div id="search_query"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd file name:instant1.js

```
$('#go').keyup(function(){
var search_query=$(this).val();

$.post('search1.php',{search_query:search_query},function(searchq){

$('#search_query').html(searchq);
 });
```

});

Third file name :search1.php

```
<?
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
 mysql_select_db("sachin");

 if(isset($_POST['search_query'])){
 echo $_POST['searchquery'];
 ?>
```

now i am  just simply trying to display the search done in indexmain.php but it is not displaying any results even when i just try to echo the searched query.do help mates...

Comment: You need to close this tag at your first file: `<html lang="en"` and making it `<html lang="en">`

Comment: sorry it was a typo error....

Comment: make sure you have enabled short_tags in your php.ini or replace <? with <?php. Also - you are checking for `search_query` but echoing `searchquery` - does are different keys

Comment: You didn't close the `if` in your search1.php file

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the character encoding in HTML file as META tag.

Answer (score 0):

For your query to display all characters, you need to replace in your search1.php file before "if" with this:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

mysql_select_db("sachin");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

I'm sure that in your search1.php file there is more code that what you wrote in here...
you have an IF statement that is not followed by else and no closing "}"...

That UTF8 is everything.
Let me know if it works. On my script did.

Comment: hi there.... its an old question asked in december.sory but i don't remember what i did at that tym but i sorted it out.. thaxs for ur concern anyhow.. thnxs!!